# how to hitTest a DataGridView in DoubleClick event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to `hitTest` a `datagridview` the `doubleclick` event of that `datagridview`. Since it's `doubleclick` event you simply have `eventArgs` and not a `MouseEvent`, so I don't know where the `doubleclick` was performed.

I tried with the `Cursor.Position` but it wasn't successful.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Here is the function:

```
private void dgvFormulaires_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvFormulaires.Rows.Count == 0)
        return;

    DataGridView.HitTestInfo test = dgvFormulaires.HitTest(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
    if(test.RowIndex >= 0)
        btnGestForm.PerformClick();
}
```

the row index is always `-1` with that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this line

```
DataGridView.HitTestInfo test = dgvFormulaires.HitTest(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
```

with those 2 lines and now it work good

```
System.Drawing.Point pt = dgvFormulaires.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
DataGridView.HitTestInfo test = dgvFormulaires.HitTest(pt.X, pt.Y);
```

Comment: Any ideas how you would HitTest a DataGridRow relative to the gridview ?

Comment: @eranotzap I'm not quite sure why you would want to do that. By getting the `HitTestInfo` you are getting the row and the column where the hit was made.